# How to refresh an iFrame in blazor with .NET 5?

Tags: javascript, iframe, blazor, .net-5

I can't refresh an iframe in a razor page(project : blazor wasm with .NET 5).
My javascript function is:

```
function RefreshIFramesDashboard()
    {
        var elts = document.getElementsByClassName("refresh");
        for (var elt in elts)
        {
            alert(elt.src);
            elt.src += '';
        }
    }
```

and the iframe take a lot of time to grab datas from the report  server, but when the iframe is filled, I trigger the javascript function above and nothing happens : no refresh, and the 'alert' prompts 'Undefined'.

I wonder if the javascript code is aware that the iframe has been filled.

here is the iFrame call:

```
<iframe src=@($"http://localhost/ReportService?blahblahblah") scrolling="no" style="width:625px;height:600px" frameborder="0"  class="refresh"/>
```

it contains (in blahblahblah) some references to C# properties (for example '{MyProperty1}').

any help appreciated.

Comment: `for (propertyName in object)` returns the property-name, not the value. You have to use `for (propertyValue of object)` or `object[propertyName]` inside the loop.

Comment: ok, thanks. it works. You can make an answer of that if you want.

Comment: @Christopher, you've clearly answered the question, go ahead and post it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for (propertyName in object)` returns the property-name, not the value.

You have to use `for (propertyValue of object)` or `object[propertyName]` inside the loop.